# Replace the word in String in java

Tags: java

how we change the value "the" with "That" in this string"There is the book of Real Story.The Story behind the book is about a hero her wife and Their children"

Answer (score -1):

You could have looked a bit more into the String class, the is a method available.

```
String sentence = "There is the book of Real Story. The Story behind the book is about a hero her wife and Their children";
sentence.replace("the","that");
```